# Recover git branch

Tags: git

I had repository called A. From this I branched B, and had some changes and committed it but not pushed to remote. After sometime, I deleted folder A from system (disk). Is there a way I can get the branch B again?

Comment: If you deleted the local repo with the `.git` directory in it, and never cloned or copied it anywhere else, you are out of luck. This is more in the realm of file recovery--maybe [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) would be a better bet? In the meantime, if this was a recent snafu, **shut down your machine and don't touch** if you want to to maximize your chances of successful recovery. **Good luck!** We've all been there one way or another before.

Comment: Git stores everything in the hidden `.git` dir in your repo, so if you deleted that I fear there is no way you get your stuff back. :(

Comment: Thanks for the response guys!

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. Unfortunately Git changes that haven't been pushed to the remote repository only exist on your local machine... which by the sounds of it, you have deleted. You might be able to try some recovery software, data still exists on the disk (the memory in that location will contain whatever was stored in there) until it is written over but its best to do the recovery *as soon as possible* as it's only a matter of time before that same memory is written over by something else which could be any old file or process that could cause that to happen.